# Gap between link and paragrath missing using css flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm using css flexbox for the first time and I am creating a paragraph with a link for my footer i.e.

```
<p class="footer--credit">link 2 <a href="#">company</a>.</p>
```

Flexbox somehow removes the gap after link 2, see here

```css
body{
  background: red;
}.footer__contents {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 70px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    color: $white;
    background:pink;
}
a {
        color: $orange;
        text-decoration: none;
}
p {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer__contents">
  <p class="footer--credit">link 2 <a href="#">company</a>.</p>
  <p class="footer--credit">link 1 <a href="#">company</a>.</p>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: please consider reading all the answer in the duplicate to understand why there is no gap and why you shouldn't use flexbox this way

Comment: you are already using CSS grid, so remove everything from the `p` and simply add to it `margin: auto;` to center

Answer (score 1):

Add `white-space: pre-wrap;`

```css
body{
  background: red;
}.footer__contents {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 70px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    color: $white;
    background:pink;
}
a {
        color: $orange;
        text-decoration: none;
}
p {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer__contents">
  <p class="footer--credit">link 2 <a href="#">company</a>.</p>
  <p class="footer--credit">link 1 <a href="#">company</a>.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: OMG, I could not figure that out but I knew it was something silly like that. Thank you.

Comment: @Dan this is a *hack*, add line break or more space and you will have more issues (https://jsfiddle.net/3cf9ru0d/ / https://jsfiddle.net/3cf9ru0d/2/)

Comment: @TemaniAfif do you have a solution?

Comment: @Dan added 2 duplicates with the needed solution .. you don't have to use flexbox with text container (here is another issue : https://jsfiddle.net/3cf9ru0d/4/) .. flexbox is not an automatic solution for everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issue by adding `margin-left: 5px;` in `a` CSS.

```
a {
    color: $orange;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Another option you can use space **HTML Entities**.

> **HTML Entities Reference Link -** https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

```
<div class="footer__contents">
  <p class="footer--credit">link 2&nbsp;<a href="#">company</a>.</p>
  <p class="footer--credit">link 1&nbsp;<a href="#">company</a>.</p>
</div>
```

```css
body{
  background: red;
}.footer__contents {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 70px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    color: $white;
    background:pink;
}
a {
        color: $orange;
        text-decoration: none;
        margin-left: 5px;
}
p {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer__contents">
  <p class="footer--credit">link 2 <a href="#">company</a>.</p>
  <p class="footer--credit">link 1 <a href="#">company</a>.</p>
</div>
```